# select a file with forbidden name in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, cmd, openfiledialog

There are some names in windows which are called "forbidden names" and its not possible to name files with those specific names in windows explorer. such as aux , com , prn ... but its possible to use those names using cmd prompt.

example: ren \.\fold\a.txt aux.txt

after that the file wont be deleted or renamed or written.

i'm programming a software which renames a usual file to aux and also renames the forbidden file to another usual name. but the issue is that OpenFileDialog cannot select the files containing "aux" name. so that i must ask the client to select the files parent folder and then select the file via a listbox

:( which makes the software look so terrible. do you know any way to make the OpenFileDialog , select the file?

Comment: If you told us why you want to use reserved names for files perhaps we could suggest something that does not use those names.

Comment: They are not "forbidden" they are used. `if exist aux echo exists` shows every directory already have an Aux file.

Comment: Dear @andrew-morton . The OpenFileDialog object can not select that file and add its address to the textbox. thats my problem. and the program must use those names cuz then it will be undeletable by windows explorer and its one of the things my program must do "making files undeletable" :D